# How to perform Arithmetic right shift on a 64 bit number stored across two 32 bit registers in ARM?

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am trying to implement the booth's multiplication algorithm in ARM assembly language.

```
Algorithm 2: Booth’s Algorithm to multiply two 32-bit numbers to produce a 64-bit result
Data: Multiplier in V , U = 0, Multiplicand in N
Result: The lower 64 bits of UV contain the result
1 i←0
2 prevBit ← 0
3 fori<32do
4 i←i+1
5 currBit ← LSB of V
6 if (currBit,prevBit) = (1,0) then
7 U←U−N
8 end
9 else if (currBit,prevBit) = (0,1) then
10 U←U+N
11 end
12 prevBit ← currBit
13 UV ← UV ≫ 1 (arithmetic right shift)
14 end
```

How do I perform the 13th step of the algorithm ? How do I perform asr on a 64 bit number stored as 32 bit parts on two registers ?

I have tried performing asr on both of the registers and then for the lower 32 bits I replace the MSB with the LSB of the upper 32 bits (stored before performing asr).

Comment: Ask a compiler: `int64_t asr(int64_t a){ return a>>1; }`  (variable-count shifts are harder, but compilers can still show you how): https://godbolt.org/z/67drx6M7e .  The low half is effectively unsigned, so you just want to `lsr` to make room to OR in bits from the high half.  Near duplicate of [How to rotate and shift a 64-bit integer on ARM Cortex-M3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65764517) which shows left-shift.

Comment: @PeterCordes Note that the 1-bit left shift is special because it can be combined with the carry-in via "adc". Furthermore, 1-bit right shift can be accomplished tersely the help of `rrx`. (Though terse may not be the same as efficient.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: 1-bit right shift can, too, via `rrx` to shift C into the top of the low half.  Clang does that, IDK why GCC misses it, unless it's slow.  https://godbolt.org/z/Yc8GncbPh   (And IDK why Clang `-mthumb` is using `asrs.w` when `asrs r1, r1, #1` is encodeable.)  I'll post an answer since I didn't find an exact duplicate.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, I forgot to mention `rrx` initially. (I edited while you were replying.) Note also that you can do this all in one instruction on ARM: `smull`. But I assume OP is implementing by hand for the experience/practice.

Answer (score 3):

Ask a compiler: `int64_t asr_1(int64_t a){ return a>>1; }`.
[**Godbolt compiler explorer**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgDspAAOqAqETgwe3r56KWmOAiFhkSwxcVwArLaY9gUMQgRMxARZPn4BdpgOGQ1NBEUR0bEJto3NrTlco30DJWUSFQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CbbbgoE%2BIIAdAgn2CYaAIIPj6EEAGySAPoEh0wKxC%2BXAgb0%2BPz%2BixM8SsT0OcMOxEwBDWDD%2BdzuXBOMOe8QAIi8XqDvr9/oC0AxziDBGCSZDoS94QikSi0dt7myKliCXiCU8ieDSV9yecvlE8MAqR9iRCodjGYjkcRUUx0WyINszNYllynlD8bq%2BdTpaTJTS/qRDm9Dsg6XL4QqWSq2XdTNtsXqXhxlrROBVeH4OFpSKhOG5rNZDgpVutMMczNseKQCJovcsANYgbYADiuAE5c%2B9c/Ftu8zMX41mzFUfRxJP6U8HOLwFCANEmU8s4LAYIgUKgWEk6LFyJQ0AOh3EmixgFwNW2aLQCLEWxAog2xcxiABPTiJjdNLcAeSi2i6ye4vDHbEEh4YtB3gd4WCiXmAbjEtBbF9IWBYhmA4iPj%2BeCIt0ABumBfkGmCqF0XhLruvBvDUDa0HgUTEAeHhYA2BDEHgLCIcsVAGMACgAGp4JgADuh5JIwiEyIIIhiOwUhMfIShqA2ujbPo/4oOGlj6OhLaQMsqBJHUX4ALSHtshwySwJGoEwBAyUwYonLiUZUL8SnIEkXjaWgzQwRp8TxLwqAQcQ%2BFYGJEDLJ03TOBArgTH4UzBKEgylMMUx5OkAiebkqTBQwsxDOU1S1D0YwtJ4bR6C5dS9M0UX%2BTF5x9KFUw5RlvlzAFznRhsEjer69ZASGHCHI8ABKACyhwAOJuG4hyzlcZhXBohwQLghAkHGCaLLw55aIs6YgBUbY1nWpCEfEkhXFI2zbBoZhcFmGjvFmFTbFUAZBrVzatu2j6dj2Xa9mOg70GQFAQPdE4gFOYHxDJ%2Bz/lwXAaFMC5LsQK5rkB%2B7boxENHieZ6MVejAELe94Ns%2Br7vrQn6Mb%2B/6AUG%2BCgY4EFQbwMFwQh37ITWQZoRhWEYJsQZ4QRRF8KRFFUbR9EBom/DMaI4jsXznEqOoQG6FMBhGIJljWCJUSORJUkZLJh5mIpADqH6KSwhnGdsuKmUuqgWVZwa2fZkHwM5NRnhkLgMO4SWTIEjuZfMgXhXUeXJF7GTuwFsV2wI6WJdkXlB659QJQH2UJT7BX9EV0UVSsazlVwlUcH6pAndZnB/MQLCfRp1pS8AXVcH1a0DUNRDEKNmcTR2ywIJgTBYHETmkBmc36Jwi2EX3eeNhw51tpNXqkLdEBIK9j0ji9/YPcMH1fT9Rh/QDfB0MDoPrqEB5Q4f27HqeDjw/215I3eD745gL5vh%2BX6JjjRh40%2BIF28TDZk8g8GbETFTVC6FMLbmwozCa%2BFCIXmIuzSiNE6IMW/MLFigtpDC0UKLHi/h%2BLS1MLLYStNFbBmVgIVW6sZJa0xjrPWJkSDG1NjrAgCBojWQtngBy1tI51Adk7cOegfLFBTlwAIQVvbOwjuI/2ycsoSA6LbKOocE6KLSjHWRHt8rx0kSldRwi5F/VKunNiWcc4j1qoXYuX0mBl3/JXauXBa74Hro3cal0pqt3bp3SgWdB6zTbOYpstgLqT2mj3fx/cODbGqqdIJoSZrvCrhoDQm0zDvG2PENJ8RElZkiWYXghF/oBIbGddxqY8kxPzmPMpYTbJpGcJIIAA) with GCC and clang for ARM

In the standard calling convention, the first arg and the return value are both in R1:R0 so compilers will make asm that operates in-place.
For a shift-count of 1, Clang uses the Carry flag to get the bit from the bottom of the high half to the top of the low half.

```
// clang -O2 -Wall -mcpu=cortex-a77
        asrs    r1, r1, #1         @ set flags, including C from the bit shifted out
        rrx     r0, r0             @ rotate-through-carry, shifting C into the top
```

GCC doesn't use the carry flag, using the same strategy it and clang use for shift counts between 2 and 31.  **The low half of an `int64_t` is unsigned;** a logical shift leaves zeros where you can OR in some bits from the high half.  This strategy is less efficient than the `rrx` trick for a count of `1`, unless `rrx` is slow on some CPUs.

```
// return a>>5   with clang; GCC is similar but uses a MOV to copy R1 and OR last
        lsr     r0, r0, #5                  @ lo >>= 5
        orr     r0, r0, r1, lsl #27         @ lo|=high<<(32-5)  to shift bits between them
        asr     r1, r1, #5                  @ hi >>= 5
```

---

Clang with `-mthumb` strangely uses `asrs.w` before `rrx`, but still plain `asrs` (16-bit) for `return a>>(32+5);` which is easy: `asrs  r0, r1, #5` ; `asrs   r1, r1, #31` (high half of the return val is either all-0 or all-1, according to the sign bit.)

AFAICT there's no correctness reason for using `asrs.w`.  `asrs` is encodable as a 16-bit Thumb instruction, although `rrx` is only available with Thumb 2.  This doesn't need ARMv8 or anything, in fact `clang -march=armv4t` still uses this; I just tend to use `-mcpu=cortex-a77` or `a53` because it's recent and easy to think of, and I want to know if there are any new tricks, and for tuning choices appropriate for modern ARM cores.  `cortex-m3` or `m0` are also relevant for some projects.  M0 notably lacks most Thumb 2 encodings:

```
// GCC or Clang  -mcpu=cortex-m0
        lsls    r2, r1, #31        // extract the low bit of the high half
        lsrs    r0, r0, #1
        adds    r0, r0, r2         // and OR it in to  lo >> 1
        asrs    r1, r1, #1         // hi >>= 1
```

---

Variable-count shifts are harder, but compilers can still show you how, using predicated execution.  GCC `-marm` has the shortest out of any of it or clang's versions for `int64_t asr(int64_t a, int c){ return a>>c; }`

```
// GCC -O3 -mcpu=cortex-a77   for a variable-count shift.  Count in R2
        lsr     r0, r0, r2
        rsb     r3, r2, #32           // 32-count
        subs    ip, r2, #32           // count-32 and set flags
        orr     r0, r0, r1, lsl r3
        orrpl   r0, r0, r1, asr ip    // ORR if PLus (if Negative flag == 0)
        asr     r1, r1, r2
        bx      lr
```

ARM shifts with counts >= 32 shift out all the bits, producing zero for logical shifts.  So the `r1, lsl r3` source operand is zero if it's actually the other bits we need, I think.  And `asr r1, r1, r2` to set the high half works like `asr r1, #31` for r2==32 or higher; it's still the original input shift count.